# Refer Community Branding Information "Company Logo" in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

Is it possible to refer community branding "Company Logo" in lightning component?

When you build a custom Bolt solution, you build custom community template. Using standard design tokens, you can get look & feel from palette selected.

But how Can we refer the company logo/ Background logo uploaded in Community Branding editor.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?, please explain further.

Comment: @DaveHumm, updated the description.

Comment: Ok, I get the issue as the uploaded logo is stored in SF rather than the community and then you need to include it in a lighting bolt solution to export how can it be included.

Comment: When we upload Company logo in Community builder, how can we refer that logo in code. 
For example, we can refer profile using below code 
<aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="aura.component[]"/>
<div>
{!v.profileMenu}
</div>

.... Similarly, is there any tag to refer Company Logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, far I have found below:

1. We can use standard Community SLDS token to refer palette colors.
2. Images are stored under content. So, we can refer it from there.

Hope it will help someone.